# How to change 1.3445 to 13445, 2.4444 to 24444 , and keep 1.20 not change

Tags: r, string, stringr

How to change 1.3445 to 13445, 2.4444 to 24444 , and keep 1.20 not change. Thanks!

```
   md <- data.frame(value=c('1.3445','1.20','2.4444'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code, it's ok . Here just mark it

```
md %>% mutate(value_new=if_else(grepl("([1-9]{1,}).([0-9]{4})",value),
                                str_remove_all(value,'\\.'),value))
```